# Working with events when clicking an item within a list javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, right now I have an html list and some javascript code to go with it. When an item in this list is clicked, it is bolded. This all works fine.

```
<ul>
    <li>apple</li>
    <li>orange</li>
    <li>banana</li>
</ul>
<!--result is an empty div, for now -->
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
    var list = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

    function markSelection() {
        if (this.style.fontWeight !== "bold") {
            this.style.fontWeight = "bold";
        } else {
            this.style.fontWeight = "normal";
        }
    }

    for (i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; i++) {
        list[i].onclick = markSelection;
    }
</script>
```

But, when I add some html to a div using javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";
        $(result).html("<ul><li>apple</li><li>orange</li><li>banana</li></ul>");
    });
```

the onclick bolding doesn't work for the items in *this* list. I'm not sure why. Here is a fiddle to show what I mean. The "dropdown" list isn't clickable but the bottom list is. http://jsfiddle.net/avfyvk2v/11/

Any idea how to make the dropdown list item bold on click?

**UPDATE**

I'm thinking it might be because I grab `var list = document.getElementsByTagName("li");` before I add the new list. Working now, let me know if you have input. Thanks!

Comment: The items are being added after the listeners are attached, meaning the listeners aren't being subsequently attached to them too

Comment: I tried adding `list = document.getElementsByTagName("li");` after adding the new HTML but no luck. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sure found an excellent way to complicate that one

```js
$('#result').on('click', 'li', function() {
    $(this).css('font-weight', function(_, w) {
        return w === 'bold' ? 'normal' : 'bold';
    });
});

$('#result').html("<ul><li>apple</li><li>orange</li><li>banana</li></ul>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: "You sure found an excellent way to complicate that one" lol thanks for the help. As you can tell I'm new to web dev!

Comment: Learning plain javascript is good, and it helps a lot, but if you're already using jQuery, try sticking to most of the simple methods it provides, it makes it a lot easier to  write good code.

Comment: Gotchya, will def start to use as much jQuery. Thanks for the tip

Comment: I didn't know you could run/include code snippets. That is just too cool.

Answer (score 1):

Use full power of jQuery:

```
$('#result').on('click', 'li', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('bold');
});
```

In this case the event will fire for all `li` elements inside `#result` even if they were created dynamicaly. Also toggling css class will save some space.

http://jsfiddle.net/semencov/kn0w1y8m/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

function markSelection() {
    if (this.style.fontWeight !== "bold") {
        this.style.fontWeight = "bold";
    } else {
        this.style.fontWeight = "normal";
    }
}
$('body').on('click', 'li', markSelection);
```

It will make jquery add a click event on every `li` element that are child of the `body` element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, First add listelement to html and then apply click event:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";
        $(result).html("<ul><li>apple</li><li>orange</li><li>banana</li></ul>");
    });

 var list = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

    function markSelection() {
        if (this.style.fontWeight !== "bold") {
            this.style.fontWeight = "bold";
        } else {
            this.style.fontWeight = "normal";
        }
    }

    for (i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; i++) {
        list[i].onclick = markSelection;
    }
```